# Why does the compiler seem to ignore if statements in templated classes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

First off, the code

```
vector<T> kvec;

for (ulong kv = 0; kv < ke.count; kv++)
{
    T key;
    if (typeid(T) != typeid(QUAT32))
    {


        fread(&key, sizeof(T), 1, fh);
    }
    else{

        shortQuat key16;

        fread(&key16, sizeof(shortQuat), 1, fh);
        key.Parse(key16);

    }
    kvec.push_back(key);
}
```

the following compiler error is thrown at `key.Parse(key16);` :

```
error C2039: 'Parse' : is not a member of 'libm2::VEC3F'
```

Of course it doesn't; but the problem is that anything with the type of VEC3F shouldn't even get there. Obviously the compiler is using the first type that gets sent to the class that snippet is from, which is fine - but why ignore the conditional?

And yeah, if I comment that line out, it compiles fine - and the conditional works fine at runtime.

So I guess the real question is, what's the best way to deal with this, without having to duplicate an entire class for one specialized type?

Comment: The `if` runs at runtime, not compile time. Use template specialization instead (put the code in a templated function, and specialize that function for `QUAT32`).

Comment: I was afraid of that - but I didn't want to have to duplicate a huge section of code for one small, infrequent occurrence. So I came up with a hackish solution. Will post below.

Comment: I'm not sure I see where the duplication would come from. It's simply a matter of moving the code that's inside your `if` block and `else` block into two functions (and calling them appropriately).

Comment: Does that mean there's a limit to how far the compiler goes? Because even if I forked that out to a templated function, I'd still have to do a type comparison, somewhere.

Comment: I'll provide some code when I have a few minutes. It should clear up any confusion :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment:

The `if` runs at runtime, not compile time (the optimizer might remove the branch, but it has to compile in the first place to get that far).

You can use template specialization instead, which *is* done at compile time (the compiler instantiates a separate copy of the templated function for each type you give it *before* compiling it). You can provide a specialization to force a different (special) function body for particular types, which is exactly what you want in this case.

Here's an example derived from the code in your question (I'm assuming the double-push_back to `kvec` for non QUAT32s is a typo):

```
template<typename T>
inline void readKey(T& key, FILE* fh)
{
    fread(&key, sizeof(T), 1, fh);
}

template<>
inline void readKey<QUAT32>(QUAT32& key, FILE* fh)
{
    shortQuat key16;
    fread(&key16, sizeof(shortQuat), 1, fh);
    key.Parse(key16);
}

// ...
vector<T> kvec;
for (ulong kv = 0; kv < ke.count; kv++)
{
    T key;
    readKey(key, fh);
    kvec.push_back(key);
}
```

Comment: Note that you could also change `readKey` to return a copy of a T that it constructs locally (instead of passing in a reference); this could make the loop one line long (but you would lose the type inference when calling `readKey`).

Comment: That's...wow. So how does that logic work? I mean, I realize the second overload doesn't have a typename T set in the template - so I imagine that's what allows the method to be called without specifying the type - but the method specifies QUAT32...so how does readkey() get turned into readkey<T>()? And yeah that was a typo-fixed.

Comment: @Digital: It's a feature of C++ designed more-or-less for exactly this purpose :-) In this case, there's no actual function overloads, just a *template specialization* (though you can mix overloads with templates too). The first one is the general-case template for all types T. The second one *specializes* the general case for a particular type -- the compiler sees the `template<>` and adds it to its table of possible functions by that name. When it's time to instantiate the function (where it's called), it chooses a specialization if one is available, falling back to the default template.

Comment: @Digital: The `readKey` *is* `readKey<T>`, but thanks to another feature of C++, *template type inference*, we can omit the type parameters when we call it and the compiler will figure it out from the type of the argument being passed in (if possible, which it is in this case).

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain! That's actually pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**
Needed to handle a special case in a templated constructor, that needed to be converted for usefulness. But, as I feared, if statements are ignored on compile.

**Solution:**

Add a second type to the template, and create a type-cast operator in one of the types.

```
vector<T> kvec;
for (ulong kv = 0; kv < ke.count; kv++)
{
    T2 key;
    fread(&key, sizeof(T2), 1, fh);
    kvec.push_back((T)key);
}
```

In most cases, the class would be constructed like so:

```
SomeClass c = SomeClass<typeA,typeA>(fh);
```

obviously, casting between the same type should be pretty straightforward. But in the case of QUAT32...

```
SomeClass c = SomeClass<QUAT32,SHORT_QUAT>(fh);
```

the solution was to just do this:

```
typedef struct SHORT_QUAT
{
    short x;
    short y;
    short z;
    short w;
    operator const QUAT32(){
        QUAT32 q;
        q.x = float(x < 0 ? x + 32768 : x - 32767) / 32767.0f;
        q.y = float(y < 0 ? y + 32768 : y - 32767) / 32767.0f;
        q.z = float(z < 0 ? z + 32768 : z - 32767) / 32767.0f;
        q.w = float(w < 0 ? w + 32768 : w - 32767) / 32767.0f;
        return q;
    }
}shortQuat;
```

and then the data that was stored in shortquat form could be cast to the more useful float format without issue.

It just seemed like a waste to have to create an entire duplicate just for a special case. I'd like to think it's the lesser of two ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to declare static variable in the template class, that stores previously defined type ID and check it when need to.

```
#define CNTYPE_NONE     0
#define CNTYPE_STRING   1
#define CNTYPE_SIGNINT  2

template <typename key_t, typename value_t>
class HashTable 
{
public:
    HashTable() {;}
    ...................
    static int m_nTypeID;
    // and later you can check the type by:    

    void SomeFunc()
    {
        if(m_nTypeID == CNTYPE_STRING) 
        {
            ................
        } 
        else 
        {
            ................
        }
    }
};

typedef HashTable<std::string, std::string> THashTableString;
typedef HashTable<int, int> THashTableSignInt;

THashTableString::m_nTypeID = CNTYPE_STRING;
THashTableSignInt::m_nTypeID = CNTYPE_SIGNINT;

int main()
{
    THashTableString strTable;
    THashTableSignInt intTable;
    .........................................        

    return 0;
}
```